# Trying to access a site with headers

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to access the site as another domain so I can read its content.

I tried to do so in such a way but without success:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://www.test.com/hello.php',
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'text',
          success: function(text) { alert(text); },
          error: function() { alert('error'); },
          beforeSend: setHeader
        });
      });

      function setHeader(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Referer', 'http://www.test.com');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Some Text</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

please help me.
Itai.

Comment: For reasons that should be fairly obvious, you can't use JavaScript to access another domain unless that domain has been specifically set up with access control headers.

Comment: To add to @NiettheDarkAbsol's comment https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: So how should this be done?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can only extract content from a page as long this site has set up an API to read content from. 
If the site is yours, maybe you should try first to make a restful API for it, so you can "send" the information as JSON to your other JS, and maybe solving it with bodyparser.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from within scripts. For example, XMLHttpRequest and the Fetch API follow the same-origin policy. This means that a web application using those APIs can only request HTTP resources from the same origin the application was loaded from, unless the response from the other origin includes the right CORS headers.

The other domains needs to respond with a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to allow your script to access the response.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS